# Finding generators for products of ideals

Tags: ideals

If you want to find the generators for the product of ideals, do you simply take all possible products of the generators in the ideals. For example, let $R$ be a ring and let $I = (a,b)$ and $J = (c,d)$. Then we have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
IJ &= \{(ax + by)(cw + dz) : w,x,y,z \in R\} \\
&= \{ac(xw) + ad(xz) + bc(yw) + bd(yz) : w,x,y,z \in R\}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

We see that $IJ$ contains all multiples of $ac,ad,bc,bd$ and their sums. So then $IJ = (ac,ad,bc,bd)$. Is this true in general?
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? To me it seems like you proved the "general" case.

Comment: Does this method work regardless of the number of ideals and generators is what I mean.

Comment: This is for a commutative ring, I presume.  Then of course, if $A$ is a set of generators of $I$ and $B$ a set of generators of $J$, $AB = \{ab \; : \; a \in A,\; b \in B\}$ is a set of generators of $IJ$.

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

> Does this method work regardless of the number of ideals and
>   generators is what I mean.

Yes, it does. Let $I = (a_1, \ldots, a_m)$ and $J = (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ be left ideals in a ring commutative ring $R$. Then
$$IJ = \{(x_1a_1 + x_1a_2 + \ldots + x_ma_m)(y_1b_1 + y_2b_2 + \ldots + y_nb_n) \}$$
and clearly $a_ib_j \in IJ$ for all $1 \le i \le m$ and $1 \le j \le n$. Conversely, every element in $IJ \setminus \{0\}$ is of the form $\sum_{i,j} z_{i,j}a_i b_j$.

An easy induction on the number of factors yields the result for $I_1I_2 \ldots I_n$ as well.

However, in a non-commutative ring we only get $(a_1, \ldots, a_m)(b_1, \ldots, b_n) \supseteq (a_ib_j)_{i,j}$.

As an example consider the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices with integer coefficients. Then 
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
$$

and thus $ \left( \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)  \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \right) = (0) $, but
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) =  \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
demonstrates $ \left( \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right),  \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \right) \neq (0)$.

Comment: this is a pedantic point, but nonetheless: technically $IJ$ is not the *set* of elements of that form, but actually the ideal *generated* by the set of elements of that form. for instance, consider $I=(x,y)$ and $J=(z,w)$ in a polynomial ring $F[x,y,z,w]$. then, for instance, $xz+yw$ is an element of $IJ$, but it cannot be written as a product of an element from $I$ and an element from $J$. nonetheless your argument still works, since showing an ideal lies in another ideal is equivalent to showing that a set of its generators does. (+1)